# How do I integrate this metric?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I have worked out a metric for a hypothetical pseudo-Riemann manifold and I'd like to explore its properties:
$$ds^2=-(at+c)^2dt^2+\left(\frac{\left(t_0^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_0^4}\right)dx^2\tag 1$$
Where $ds$ is an infinitesimal distance (assume it's $0$ for all intervals), $t_1$ and $t_0$ are the start and end of the infinitesimal chunk of time, $dt$, at time, $t$. The change in the spatial coordinates comes from this schematic representation of the line elements:

[image]

$$dx=dx_0-\frac{1}{2}(dx_0-dx_1)\tag 2$$
I get the desired distance (that is, the sum total of all $dx$s) when I perform this operation numerically (as a series of time slices), but I'm having trouble making the conceptual leap to solving it using an integral (which, as I understand it, is the primary purpose of a metric). I suspect that I can replace $t_0^2+t_1^2$ with $t^2+(t-\Delta t)^2$. It also seems to me like $dt$ is conceptually equivalent to $\Delta t$, but I can't get any further.

Comment: What integral do you wish to perform exactly?

Comment: I would like an answer for the sum of all the $dx$s given a start and end time. $ds$ can be considered 0 for this purpose.

Comment: Surely the factor in front of $dx^2$ should be dimensionless, the one you have has dimensions of time squared.

Comment: Strictly speaking what you want isn't clearly defined as a metric, most likely because of the conceptual leg work you did to numerically verify the thing you were making. What was it that this metric was trying to accomplish? I can try to help you find the correct way to write it down, since an infinitesimal time interval does not have a well defined start and end time.

Comment: Do you mean $\int\limits_{x(t_0)}^{x(t_1)}dx$ ? If you set $ds=0$ the isn't this $\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_1}dt \ |A/B|$ where $ds^2=-A^2dt^2+B^2dx^2$?

Comment: _"What was it that this metric was trying to accomplish?"_ It is trying to calculate the physical distance that a photon would travel in a given time interval in a quadratically expanding manifold. The spatial term represents the change in the coordinate space for a given time interval, $dt$.

Comment: @Quarkly I see what you're saying, that's what the $ds=0$ would accomplish and that is true for any metric. What I mean is what was the purpose of that specific $a(t)$ term? It's intriguing and I want to make it work the way you intended since right now it is nonsense.

Comment: @Sal - Actually, I think I mean $$\int^{t0}_{t1} f(t) dt = \Delta x$$Where $\Delta x$ is the total change in the spatial coordinates.

Comment: @Quarkly For which function $f(t)$?

Comment: @Sal - The function $f(t)$ is what I'm looking to get from Eq (1). I know it isn't in the right form, but I can't connect the concepts of a $\Delta t$ and a $dt$. I can do it in code, but not in a metric formula. I want to alter Eq (1) so that it yields $f(t)$.

Comment: Schematically one has $\sum_i f(x_i)\to\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int dx \ f(x)$ which in the appropriate limit is the definition of a Riemann integral. The $\Delta x$ is not what you call $\Delta x$. However, here, it seems you want to find $x_1-x_0=\int_{x_0}^{x_1} dx$ which may be written as $\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_1}\frac{dx}{dt}dt$ and $dx/dt$ may be found in terms of $t$ using your equation: $dx/dt=|(at+c)2t/(t_0^2 +t_1^2)|$ where I have set $ds=0$ as requested.

Comment: That said I agree with the other comments that the second terms on RHS of (1) is strange viz. your interpretation of $t_0$ and $t_1$. Are you certain it should not read something like $ds^2=-(\cdots)dx^2+(t/t_0)^2dt^2$? For some parameter $t_0$? I think you'll have to tell us precisely how you arrived at (1)

Comment: Without further intervention, the entire term $\left( \frac{(t_0^2+t_1^2)^2}{4t_0^4}\right)$ is a *constant* which I doubt is your intent (?). Following your interpretation, I write $t_1=t_0+dt=t+dt$ with which $\left( \frac{(t_0^2+t_1^2)^2}{4t_0^4}\right) = 1 + \mathcal{O}(dt/t)$. The choice of interval will not affect this (eg $t_1=t+dt/2$). Consequently, I think the metric simplifies to $ds^2=-(at+c)^2dt^2+dx^2$, at least from my interpretation

Comment: @Sal - My intension for the second term of the RHS is more like this $$\frac{(t^2+(t-\Delta t)^2)^2}{4t^4}$$but as I mentioned at the start, I still can't get rid of the $\Delta t$ in the final form of the equation. It doesn't feel natural that it should be an input to the function (e.g. $\int_{t1}^{t0}f(t,\Delta t)dt=...$)

Comment: Aha! The expression $\frac{(t^2+(t-\Delta t)^2)^2}{4t^4}$ is equal to $1$ plus terms multiplied by $\delta t$. These terms will vanish in the limit $\delta t\to 0$, which is presumably the limit in which your sum becomes an integral. Using this, and my prior comment, we find the `sum of $dx$'s' as $x_\text{final}-x_\text{initial}=\int\limits_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \ |at+c|=c(t_f-t_i)+\frac{a}{2}(t_f^2-t_i^2)$, which assumes $at+c>0$ over the integration

Comment: $dt$ is not quite conceptually equivalent to $\Delta t$. The easiest way to describe the difference is that $\Delta t$ is a coordinate on the manifold itself, while $dt$ is a coordinate on the tangent space to that manifold. As they get smaller, each becomes a better approximation to the other, but they are not identical.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - Thank you. That's useful background and makes sense intuitively, but how does it help me solve the original problem? I need a metric formula that will yield $\frac{dx}{dt}$ such that it can be used in the integral $$\int_{t1}^{t0}\frac{dx}{dt}dt=\int_{t1}^{t0}f(t)dt=x_0-x_1$$So far, the only solution I've found involves making $\Delta t$ a parameter to the function (e.g. $\int_{t1}^{t0}f(t,\Delta x)dt=x_0-x_1$)

Comment: These are comments, not answers. If I had meant to answer your question, i would have done so properly. Instead I just wanted to point out a minor correction to your understanding, so I made a comment. Though my point does relate to a very significant issue in your question (there is no such thing as $t_0$ or $t_1$, just $t$), I admit it does not address that particular issue in any way that would be helpful (nor had I intended it to). Later when I have the time, I will provide an answer that will at least address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The classic concept of a differential has always been a troublesome idea in mathematics. Berkeley castigated them as "the ghosts of departed quantities", a humorous description that is none-the-less quite apt. As long as the quantity is still around, the ghost has no power. That is the issue with your "metric" - you are attempting to have the quantity and the ghost at the same time.

Mathematicians have invented several rigorous approaches to differentials, each with its own advantages and disadvantages. Without going into the weeds, perhaps the simplest is to consider any statement about differentials as being a differential equation on some curve. That is, there is some smooth curve $\gamma(u)$ on your manifold. $x$ and $t$ are functions on that manifold, so $x \equiv x\circ \gamma(u)$ and $t \equiv t\circ\gamma(u)$ are smooth functions on a real variable. $s$ is arclength along the curve from some initial point $\gamma(u_0)$, and as such $s$ is also a function of $u$. The differential equation becomes:
$$\left(\frac{ds}{du}\right)^2 = -(at + c)\left(\frac{dt}{du}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\left(t_0^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_0^4}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)^2$$
(Because $s$ only appears in a derivative, the expression does not depend on $u_0$.) Now $t$ is still this function of the location in space, and therefore well defined for any $u$, but what are $t_0$ and $t_1$? How do they depend on $u$?

We can take one of them to be $t$ (it doesn't matter which). But the other is supposed to differ from it by "$\Delta t$". What $\Delta t$? There is no such parameter. Differential equations occur at single points, not between two points. They are often obtained as an infinitesimalized version of a delta equation between two points, but that infinitesimalization always reduces to the behavior at a single point, not two. Only the lowest order terms in the deltas survive it to become differentials. Higher order terms all go to $0$. In the case of your $t_0$ and $t_1$, if we set $t_0 = t$ and $t_1 = t + \Delta t$, then the lowest order term in $\frac{\left(t_0^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_0^4}$ is just $1$. This naive guess would make your metric
$$ds^2 = -(at + c)dt^2 + dx^2$$
But I don't know how you arrived at that expression, and a more careful analysis of your situation may provide a different answer. But if done correctly it will not involve $t_0$ and $t_1$.

Comment: Alright, so I think I understand what you're saying. Please correct what I get wrong. You're saying that it's a valid metric, in that there's an analytical solution, but it's not a metric that can be integrated because the $g_{11}$ term approaches unity as $t_0\Rightarrow t_1$? Do we agree that it's a valid metric tensor, but not one that can be integrated?

Comment: No your metric tensor is not valid. there is no "$t_0$" or "$t_1$". One of those can be $t$, but the other has no meaning. Metrics occur at single points, not two points.

Comment: Here's the part that one of us is missing. As the time between Point A and Point B approaches zero, then the change in spatial coordinates also approaches zero. That is as dt⇒0, dx⇒0. This is true of any model of expansion. Without a positive change in time (dt > 0), there is no expansion to measure. This appears to me to disqualify the integral as a tool to calculate distance on an expanding manifold.

Comment: $dt \ne \Delta t, dx \ne \Delta x$. Differentials are not quite the same thing as deltas, and integration is not quite a summation. As I mentioned at the start of the post, the naive concept of a differential is highly problematic from a mathematical standpoint. Mathematicians have come up with several ways of defining things that *mostly* behave like we want differentials to behave, but they are all *far* removed from this naive concept you are complaining about. This is why I re-interpreted the differential equation into a equation of derivatives along a curve.

Comment: Derivatives are preferably NOT thought of as "ratios of differentials", but rather as ordinary functions that are obtained by a certain limit process from the original function.